# Are there nontrivial rational solutions of $x^{n-m}=(1+t^m)/(1+t^n)$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, rational-points

Let $n-m \ge 2$ be two fixed natural numbers. Are there any nontrivial rational solutions of the equation $$x^{n-m}=(1+t^m)/(1+t^n)$$ for $x$ and $t$? As particular cases the 
 rational solutions of the equations $x^2=(1+t^2)/(1+t^4)$ and $x^2=(1+t^3)/(1+t^5)$ will be interesting.

Comment: I think your first example (2,4) asks for coprime integers  r and s with $r^4 + s^4$ being twice a square.  With the exception of r=s=1 (and maybe one example of Ljunggren), I believe there are no examples.  It was shown by Fermat that the sum of two biquadrates is never a square.  I think you can find literature supporting my belief.  Gerhard "Have Faith In The Impossibilities" Paseman, 2018.01.31

Comment: thanks for your comments.how do you convert my problem to Fermat problem?

Comment: By representing t as a fraction with coprime integers s and r.  You should get that 2 is the only possible prime divisor that cancels.  Gerhard "That And Some Algebra Too" Paseman, 2018.01.31.

Comment: I do not understand how the problem converts to the above problem.  By letting  t=s/r we get x^2(s^4+r^4)=t^4+s^2r^2. then?

Comment: please explain more about the first case.of course I know that  Fermat case has not solution... And what do you think about the second example?

Comment: You need to do a little more work to take the right hand side and convert it to a fraction of square integers. When you do this, the primary issue that arises is if (part of) the denominator is twice a square. This is routine algebraic manipulation.  If you do not see this, my first guess is that this is the wrong forum for your comments.  Gerhard "Likely There Aren't Interesting Solutions" Paseman, 2018.01.31.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Indeed, the equation $X^4 + Y^4 = 2Z^2$ has the only integer solution $(X,Y,Z)=(u,u,u^2)$, which is coprime only for $u=\pm 1$. However, if I've not mistaken, the case $(n,m)=(4,2)$ reduces to a different equation: $X^2 + Y^2 = 2Z^4$. Do you have some other reduction in mind?

Comment: Yes but it could be an error.  Let t=r/s and get an expression r^2+ s^2 times s^2 in the numerator and r^4 + s^4 in the denominator, and worry about cancellation.  Later I will see about recovering my thought process.  Gerhard "Working On Different Recovery Presently" Paseman, 2018.02.01.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, t=1 is a solution, but we count that as trivial and move on.

As polynomials in t, we have a ratio of (some products of) cyclotomic polynomials, and the gcd for most choices will be $1+ t^d$ when $d$ is  gcd of m and n and both m/d and n/d are odd. Removing that as a common factor, it is unlikely that what remains has any chance of yielding a comparable power of a rational number.

For m=2 and n=4, we consider t in reduced form as r/s, and look for coprime integers r and s such that the ratio of $(r^2 + s^2)s^2$ to $r^4 + s^4$ is the ratio of two integer squares. Since r and s are coprime, the only common divisor of the two terms can be 1 or 2. Fermat says no for 1, and Max says no for 2.

For m=3 and n=5, we can divide out by (1+t) and note that the two polynomials are coprime. Again picking r and s coprime, we need $u=r^2 -rs + s^2$ to be a square, and the denominator $D$ to be a square.  We then find $D-u^2$ is $rs(u-rs)$ with $u-rs$ also being a square. We also have $D-r^2s^2$ is $r ^2 + s^2$ times the square $u$.  While these conditions do not lead to a contradiction, I strongly suspect a similar manipulation will.

Granville recently proved a result regarding certain sequences having primitive prime factors to an odd power.  I suspect that can be used to tackle the case n-m is even. I will include the reference later in a comment.

Gerhard "Sorry, The Contradiction Went Elsewhere" Paseman, 2018.02.01.

Comment: $x = 1$ instead of $t = 1$, I guess.

Comment: Actually "gives" instead of "is".  But I will leave it as is.  Gerhard "Solutions Can Also Be Indirect" Paseman, 2018.02.01.

Comment: thank you very much for your valuable comments. I think that there exist integers n,m such that the equation has nontrivial solutions. What do you think about this?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what I was thinking.  Clearly $t = 1$ does indeed give a solution.

Comment: thanks, but t=0,1,-1 are trivial solution.

Comment: Dear Alekseyev ; very thanks, note that by letting x=p/q, t=r/s in the equation, we get the relation $p^2s^4+p^2r^4-q^2s^4-q^2s^2r^2=0$ which is not equivalent with $p^2s^4+p^2r^4-2r^2s^2q^2-2s^4q^2=0$.(this is obtained after some simplification in  the above relation.) !! Am I saying right?

Comment: @mehdibaghalaghdam: Indeed, I lost a couple of coefficients. The correct equation is
$$(2r^2p^2 - s^2q^2)^2 + (2s^2p^2-s^2q^2)^2 = 2(sq)^4.$$

Comment: Yes. This is right. thank you very much for your comments. we know that the soution of the equation x^2+y^2=2z^4 is (u^2,u^2,u). Then we get (2r^2p^2-s^2q^2=2s^2p^2-s^2q^2 , i.e., r=s or t=1 which leads to the trivial solution t=r/s=1. Then the case 2,4 has only trivial solution.

Comment: @mehdibaghalaghdam: $(u^2,u^2,u)$ is not the only solution to $X^2+Y^2=2Z^4$. E.g., $((u^2+1)(u^2+2u-1),(u^2+1)(u^2-2u-1),u^2+1)$ is another one.

Comment: @mehdibaghalaghdam: Anyway, reduction proposed by Gerhard Paseman works better here. I've shown mine just out of curiosity.